# $L$-Zariski closure of subgroup $SL_n(F)$ as subset of $M_n(F)$ also a subgroup of $SL_n(F)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $F$ be a field, and $SL_n(F)$ be the group of $n \times n$ matrices with determinant $1$. Let $\Gamma \subset SL_n(F)$ be a subgroup. We can consider $\Gamma$ to be a subset of $M_n(F) \cong F^{n^2}$ to define its $F$-Zariski closure. How do I prove that it is also a subgroup of $SL_n(F)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $SL_n(F)$ is a topological group in the Zariski topology. I'm going to call the subgroup $G$ because I'm typing on a cell phone, and let the closure be $H$. If $g,h\in H$, let $U$ be a neighborhood of $gh$. Since multiplication is continuous, there exist neighborhoods $A$ of $g$ and $B$ of $h$ such that $AB\subseteq U$. Since both $A$ and $B$ contain elements of $G$, so must $U$. Therefore $gh\in H$.  Note also that since inversion is a homeomorphism, if $U$ is a neighborhood of $g$ then $U^{-1}$ is a neighborhood of $g^{-1}$, and since the former neighborhood contains an element of $G$, so does the latter. This $g^{-1}\in H$, so $H$ is a subgroup of $SL_n(F)$.